# Агар или агар-агар?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вещество, добываемое из водорослей и идущее на производства мармелада, называют то "агар", то "агар-агар". Второй вариант звучит как-то по-туземному.)))
А как правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В языках полинезийской группы двойное повторение слова - это обозначение категории множественного числа. Например, на индонезийском оrang - человек, а orang-orang -люди. Если водоросль с тех краёв, то правильными будут оба варианта.